# i have done "!pip install pandas" but Jupyter still dont find it

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

i first use jupyter notebook. 
i tried to run

```
import pandas as pd
```

but it returns

```
No module called pandas
```

i've tried

```
!pip install pandas
```

it run successlfully 
jupyter show installing process

but after pandas installed, it still return

```
No module called pandas
```

when i run

```
import pandas as pd
```

why ? and how to fix it

Comment: Did you restart Jupyter after installing Pandas?

Comment: Show your `pip --version` and your `python --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have multiple pythons installed. See instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)